# How to pass data from activity to class in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-custom-view

How to pass the data from activity to class . ?
My Lock screen class is mentioned below. I want to pass the data from      activity to this Lock Screen class.

Please anyone help me ?

```
Lock Screen class
*****************

public class LockScreen extends Activity{

public WindowManager winManager;
public RelativeLayout wrapperView;

public int background;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
```

Main Activity

---

```
  public static int   backgroundPics;        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

My problem is I didn't get the updated value of background in Lockscreen class. It is always shows 0.
```

Comment: Create a `public` method in the custom `View` class that takes an `int`/`Integer` argument.

Comment: I don't see a customview here. Its a Activity. you have constructors for activity. that's bad. You need to do little bit of reading on the android docs about activity and customviews

Comment: @Raghunandan - I want to pass the updated data from activity to non-activity class

Comment: @Raghunandan : I have updated my complete code. Please help me

Comment: From where are you managing Mainactivity.backgroundPics

Comment: What is your app flow can you let me, atleast for this LockScreen. From where you are starting it

Comment: You should use application class to manage global value for the whole app or use sharedpreferences. As here you are using global variable of Mainactivity backgroundPics, creaye this in application class and use it if you want to manage this till app is running if you want to manage this backgroundpics value on restart of the app the save it in app sharedpreferences and use.

Comment: Backgroundpic selection is done using Alert dialog in Mainactivity class.
 .The changed background is affected in Mainactivity and other activities also it is saved using sharedpreference. But the change is not affected only in Lockscreen class

Comment: Where are you updating Mainactivity.backgroundPics value for this variable?

Comment: I called it on lockscreen class is : int background = Mainactivity.backgroundPics

Comment: In the Mainactivity itself. Please help me out

Comment: @Ready Android , I have updated the value in Mainactiviy itself

Comment: Sorry dear i can't help you if you will not try to understand us even you are not listening what we are trying to get from you. You are just informing which we also can see easily in your code. Do one thing move this MainActivity class variable Mainactivity.backgroundPics to application class and use it and check what is happening

Comment: @Ready Android : Can you please give me your mail Id. I will share the full code. Please help me. . Since 2 weeks I didn't get any solution regarding this.

Comment: @Ready Android : I got the solution and thanks for your help. Thanks a lot my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create a class for your requirement as CustomView and define public method to pass integer value and use it there. As I have created setIntValue().

    public class CustomView extends View {
    private int mIntValue;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setIntValue(int value) {
        //Like this you can use this integer value
        //this.mIntValue = value;
        //this.setText(value);
    }
}
```

Usage:
**1. With CustomView class instance directly:**

```
CustomView mView = new CustomView(this);
mView.setIntValue(100);
```

**2. With CustomView in layout xml:**

**In your layout xml-**

```
<your_app_package_for_custom_view_class.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/customview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**In your Activity-**

```
CustomView mView = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.customview);
mView.setIntValue(100);
```

Comment: I tried this but I didn't get the solution. My Question is "How to pass a data from activity to custom view in android ?"

Comment: But as I am seeing your question is "How to pass an integer value from main activity to custom view in android?" related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013074/how-to-pass-an-integer-value-from-main-activity-to-custom-view-in-android

Comment: What do you mean by data here? Data is what?

Comment: Here Data means an integer value. Here when I write those constructors it shows an error like  "Activity( ) in Activity cannot be applied" . I have created View using WindowManager.addview and not extends the View . Sorry if my English is bad

Comment: Show your code how you done

Comment: I have updated my code. This is my View class.I want to pass the data from Activity to Custom View

Comment: First of all remove these custructor LockScreen because these are related to View classes not for activity. And let me know for which view you want to pass integer value.

Comment: I want to pass the integer value from activity which may changed randomly and passed that updated integer value to Keyword field in the view

Comment: keywordField is a TextView, if you want to set integer value to it then can directly do it like: keywordField.setText(integerValue+""); Or if you want to pass integer value to keywordField then create a CustomTextView class as I done in my answer by extending TextView.

Comment: I want to pass the updated value from the Main activity to Custom view. Want to get the same integer value of main activity

Comment: Do one thing keywordField.setTag(yourIntegerValue); and where you want that value then fetch keywordField.getTag(); will return same value. Check it out and let me this will help

Comment: Update your latest full code in you question with what I said

Comment: I have add the new code. Please see that code

Comment: Is it working for setTag and getTag?

Comment: Suppose when I select another Integer from Activity. It is not updated in class. Integer value always shows 0. This solution is didn't work for me

Comment: Simply I need to pass updated data from activity to class

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do? Can you copy paste your full code for LockScreen activity till now you whatever you had done? And also put some comment where you want what, so I can get it easily.

Comment: I updated my code and please give me the answer. I'm completely blocked here.

Comment: Sure, will help u out